# When is PHP variable destroyed automatically?

Tags: php, variables

I am dealing uploading large .jpg image and then manipulating it through variables. At one place, I have;

> $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['smileimage']['tmp_name'])

And then later on, in a `if` case, I have to `$image = $newImage;` and after doing some work, I want the variables to be destroyed, thinking if I don't destroy them, they might just keep on eating the RAM. So I did as following:

```
if(isset($newImage)) {
    imagedestroy($newImage);
}
imagedestroy($image);
imagedestroy($thumbnail);
```

But this provides an error as

> Warning: imagedestroy(): 11 is not a valid Image resource in...

It tells erros is in line of `imagedestroy($image)`. But `$image` is a valid `image` resource. Is it that if I destroy `$newImage`, `$image` is also destroyed automatically??

But if I remove the line which says;

```
if(isset($newImage)) {
    imagedestroy($newImage);
}
```

then, there is no error. But I am worried that, if I don't destroy `$newImage` if it is set, it might just persist on the RAM and eat up the whole memory at some point?? What should I do? And also, I want to know when is the variable destroyed automatically??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you do `$image = $newImage` both variables refer to the *same* image. No copy is created. Both variables are just two different names referring to the same resource.

When you free the resource held by `$newImage` with `imagedestroy($newImage)` you are freeing the *same* resource that is held by `$image`, since they *share* it.

This is why the second call to `imagedestroy` fails, because the image no longer exists.

If you didn't manually call `imagedestroy`, PHP would have done it automatically at the end of the script.

Comment: Nice, thank you. I also want to know that, if I just leave and don't destroy `$image` & `$newImage`, do you think that, at some point, they will fill up the RAM at some point?? Or they are destroyed as soon as the session is destroyed?? Or at fix time interval?

Comment: @Sushil They get destroyed when your PHP script finishes executing. They will not fill up RAM beyond that point.

Comment: also not that an image takes raw memory bytes (from resolution/bits per pixel), not according their file size. use imagedestroy() right after you dont need the resource.

Comment: from cicada answer , you can destroy $image and after that $newImage // do a var_dumb of your vars before destroy function to be more sure